# Always got exception when using webBrowser progress changed

Tags: c#

Do you know why I always got this exception?
[image: exception]

this is my code

```
private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.MaximumProgress;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
    }
```

I would appreciate any answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress.aspx) - property `CurrentProgress` of event argument class `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs` has value -1 when download is complete.

Please use following code to ensure that progress bar completely reflects status of the download:

```
    private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.MaximumProgress;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = ((int)e.CurrentProgress < 0 || (int)e.MaximumProgress < (int)e.CurrentProgress) ? (int)e.MaximumProgress : (int)e.CurrentProgress;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will always set `e.MaximumProgress` as progress bar value because this value is always greater or equal `e.CurrentProgress`.

Comment: you should also have toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.MaximumProgress > (int)e.CurrentProgress ? e.MaximumProgress : e.CurrentProgress;

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress.aspx):

> The number of bytes that have been loaded or -1 to indicate that the download has completed.

And the -1 value is not valid progress value. And it indicates that download has completed so displaying progressbar is pointless. I think this state would be good place to hide progress window.

In your code you are casting form `long` to `int` which will cause you similar exception when you download file which size will be greater then 2,147,483,647 bytes (int.MaxValue). You should assign

```
toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = 100;
```

and in event

```
toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Floor((e.CurrentProgress / (double)e.MaximumProgress) * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if `e.CurrentProgress` is returning -1 (The number of bytes that have been loaded or the download has completed.).  You could stop the error occuring by using a conditional statement to check if the value is > -1, if it is then update the progress bar.

For example:

```
if ((int)e.CurrentProgress > -1) {
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your coding you are not checking the currentprogress value and simply assigning it to the progress bar, so the value when it is less than minimum value also been assigned to it. So, do it like below.

```
if((int)(e.CurrentProgress) > -1)
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
```

Comment: e.CurrentProgress is `long` so the parse makes no sense.

Comment: @Sai : well I have try your code but sometimes i suddenly got thsi exception, do you know how to fix it? He it is http://i.stack.imgur.com/QsAd8.png

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto - MaximumProgress doesn't work - check it, it's always the same value. So sometimes CurrentProgress > MaximumProgress, wich leads to the exception you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.CurrentProgress` is `-1`. Your minimum value is `0`.

That's why you catch exception.