# vb.net System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in progressbar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, runtime-error

I am trying to make a web browser in Visual Studio 2013 but an error keeps occuring:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

The cause is because the max progress is stuck at 10000

My code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged
    If e.MaximumProgress > 0 AndAlso e.CurrentProgress > 0 Then
        ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Value = e.CurrentProgress * 100 / e.MaximumProgress
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the error when the current progress exceeds the maximum progress which logically cant make sense.

Comment: This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/11827299/2613020

Comment: What is your .Maximumprogress value?

Comment: I stated it in the question, 10000